# aurelia-dialog TypeError: _aureliaPal.DOM.injectStyles is not a function

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

I've simply installed the aurelia-dialog plugin, version 1.0.0-beta.1.1.0, and registered it with aurelia, but I'm getting an error:

```
aurelia.use
  .plugin('aurelia-dialog');
```

> dialog-configuration.js:65 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _aureliaPal.DOM.injectStyles is not a function(…)
>
> > _apply @ dialog-configuration.js:65
> >
> > > configure @ aurelia-dialog.js:73
> > >
> > > > (anonymous function) @ aurelia-framework.js:272

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just experienced the same problem - solved it by running "jspm update", which caused several aurelia packages to be updated from beta-1.2.1 or beta-1.2.2 to rc-1.0.0 and added various other packages. Hence, the problem seems to be caused by some kind of version conflict.